# Нахождение суммы значений словарей во вложенном словаре в списке

Tags: python, list, словари, dict

**надо найти сумму баллов за экзамены и доп. баллов extra_scores**

```
candidates = [
 {"name": "Vasya",  "scores": {"math": 58, "russian_language": 62, "computer_science": 95}, "extra_scores":0},
 {"name": "Fedya",  "scores": {"math": 33, "russian_language": 85, "computer_science": 71},  "extra_scores":2},
 {"name": "Petya",  "scores": {"math": 92, "russian_language": 33, "computer_science": 82},  "extra_scores":1},
 {"name": "Gosha",  "scores": {"math": 48, "russian_language": 50, "computer_science": 68},  "extra_scores":0},
 {"name": "Masha",  "scores": {"math": 98, "russian_language": 48, "computer_science": 92},  "extra_scores":3},
]
```

**Обратиться к этим элементам могу, но просуммировать не получается**

```
print(candidates[0]['scores'])
```

Comment: А можно увидеть вашу попытку в виде кода?

Comment: Кстати не давно видел что-то похожее на этом ресурсе

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете добавить сумму баллов для всякого студента прямо в его словарь, создав для этого новый ключ, например `"sum_of_scores"`:

```
for candidate in candidates:
    candidate["sum_of_scores"] = sum([candidate["scores"][subject] 
                                          for subject in candidate["scores"]])
```

Затем вы можете комфортно выводить имена кандидатов вместе с этими суммами:

```
for candidate in candidates:
    print(f'{candidate["name"]}: {candidate["sum_of_scores"]:>3}')
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> Vasya: 215
> Fedya: 189
> Petya: 207
> Gosha: 166
> Masha: 238
> ```

---

Объяснения:

1. Я использовал так называемый *генератор списка:*

   ```
   [candidate["scores"][subject]    for subject in candidate["scores"]]
   ```

   который

   - для каждого учебного предмета (`subject`)
   - представленным ключем в словаре `candidate["scores"]`
   - поместит в этот список *значение этого ключа предмета*
     (т.е. баллы за этот предмет) - `candidate["scores"][subject]`

   Например, для кандидата "Vassya" получим тем список

   ```
   [58, 62, 95]
   ```
2. Затем я применил стандартную функцию `sum()` к этому списку.
   (Для кандидата "Vassya" получим `215` - сумму 58 + 62 + 95.)
3. Результат — сумму баллов — поместим в словарь как значение ключа
   `"sum_of_scores"`:

   ```
   candidate["sum_of_scores"] = sum( ...  )
   ```

   Хотя такой ключ в словаре `candidate` пока не существовал, он автоматически создается.
4. За двоеточием в части `{candidate["sum_of_scores"]:>3}` f-стринга:

   - знак `>` значит «заровнять вправо» (что является красивым для чисел);
     другие альтернативы: `<` влево, `^` центровать,
   - число `3` значит, сколько позиций резервируется для вывода (в их пределах будет число заровняться или центроваться).

Answer (score 0):

Я показал на примере Vasya, остальных сделаете сами

// Изменил на цикл, я надеюсь правильно понял, что вам нужно

```
candidates = [
    {"name": "Vasya",  "scores": {"math": 58, "russian_language": 62, "computer_science": 95}, "extra_scores":0},
    {"name": "Fedya",  "scores": {"math": 33, "russian_language": 85, "computer_science": 71},  "extra_scores":2},
    {"name": "Petya",  "scores": {"math": 92, "russian_language": 33, "computer_science": 82},  "extra_scores":1},
    {"name": "Gosha",  "scores": {"math": 48, "russian_language": 50, "computer_science": 68},  "extra_scores":0},
    {"name": "Masha",  "scores": {"math": 98, "russian_language": 48, "computer_science": 92},  "extra_scores":3},
]

total = candidates[0]["extra_scores"]
for i in candidates[0]["scores"]:
    total += candidates[0]["scores"][i]
```

Comment: пример показан для Fedya,  так как он находится под индексом 1, но не суть. Цель - найти универсальное решение с использованием цикла. решение в лоб не самое лучшее я думаю

Comment: Я изменил на цикл, но я до сих пор не понял, вам нужно баллы всех подсчитать или каждого по отдельности?

Comment: баллы каждого по отдельности, что бы в будущем их сравнить и составить топ лучших учеников, но это уже другая задача, пока что только найти сумму баллов кадого ученика

Comment: Отредактированный ответ в виде цикла выше

Answer (score 0):

**Я нашел решение путем создания доп. ключа sum в который и помещаю сумму баллов**
**В функции sum_balls мы находим сумму баллов для одного студента**

```
def sum_balls(student) :
return student['scores']['math'] + student['scores']['russian_language'] + student['scores']['computer_science'] + \
       student['extra_scores']
```

**Далее в функции main мы уже через enumerate через ключ получаем номер студента и в графу sum записываем результат выполнения программы sum_balls с параметром v что дает нам сумму баллов**

```
def main(candidates) :
for k, v in enumerate(candidates) :
    candidates[k]['sum'] = sum_balls(v)
candidates = sorted(candidates, key=lambda x : x['sum'], reverse=True)
for i in candidates :
    print(i)
```

**Осталось просто обозначить точку входа**

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :
main(candidates)
```